# React native on webgazer using this library

Tags: import

Is it applicable in react native? Will it work on the android applications?
It's working in localhost on how to implement it in react native

Answer (score 0):

Webgazer.js is not available on React native. As the [documentation says](https://webgazer.cs.brown.edu), it is only available on Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Edge, and Safari.

However, if you want to add it to your React Native App, you can use [react-native-webview](https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview). You'll have to build an HTML/CSS/JS app with WebGazer. Then, load it in your app using the webview library.
React-native-webview supports [iOS and Android](https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview#platforms-supported)